# ListView ItemTemplate with seperator line

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

This code from [wpf-tutorial.com](https://wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.ListView_control.ListViewItemTemplateSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ListViewItemTemplateSample" Height="150" Width="350">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvDataBinding">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Name: " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBlock Text=", " />
                        <TextBlock Text="Age: " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" (" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mail}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                        <TextBlock Text=")" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: Items with Name, age and E-Mail of persons in a ListView without separator lines.]

How can I achieve the same result but with a line separating the elements?

[image: Items with Name, age and E-Mail of persons in a ListView with horizontal red lines in between them.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an item container style to draw a border at the bottom of each container.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
   </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```